# Is there a "lite" version of the Yamaha RX-V679(BL)?

Tags: sound-system

A while ago, I asked [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2669/a-v-receiver-for-hdmi-optical-audio-in), wondering if there was a good A/V receiver that could meet my needs. I received a helpful answer, but forgot about it because of school.

I'm back looking for A/V receivers, but now that I know they tend to be more expensive, I did another Amazon search and came across [this Yamaha device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VIRG3GO). $350 doesn't seem too bad (it is as expensive as the TV it's powering, but that's alright), and it's rated highly.

The thing is, it has 6 HDMI in; I have three (+1 potential) HDMI devices. There are also 4 digital A/V in, two analog A/V in, plus two more analog audio in. It also has 7.2 surround and a "Zone 2 Party Mode" feature. That's all really nice, but I'm not sure I'll ever need that many inputs and outputs.

I do want to keep BT+WiFi if possible. I can give up the streaming options (BT works around that), but wireless control is handy (my phone does have IR, but that obviously only works in direct line of sight).

This receiver has tons of features, and it's really tempting to buy it because of that. But I don't think I have much use for everything it offers. Is there a more toned-down version of this, that's maybe a little cheaper? I only need four HDMI really, an optical audio in and one or two analog A/V in. 5.1 surround maybe.

I checked out the lower models of the V679, but they're either not available, more expensive than the higher tiers, or not cheap enough to justify the feature loss.